# Java reorder List with position number

Tags: java

I have the following code.

```
    Data d = new Data();
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    d.setName("A");
    d.setPosition(0);
    dataList.add(d);        
    
    d = new Data();
    d.setName("B");
    d.setPosition(1);
    dataList.add(d);
    
    d = new Data();
    d.setName("C");
    d.setPosition(2);
    dataList.add(d);
    
    d = new Data();
    d.setName("D");
    d.setPosition(3);
    dataList.add(d);
    
    d = new Data();
    d.setName("E");
    d.setPosition(4);
    dataList.add(d);
```

I would like to know if there is an efficient example of reordering the list **dataList** setting the position number. For example, if I set the "C" to new position 1, then the "A" will keep its position but the "B" will be changed to position 2 and the rest incrementing. As result, the "C" will have position 2 as a new result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No. What you are doing is the most efficient way. You might a little efficiency gain if you use LinkedList.

Comment: Each of your objects has a designated position. If you want to change the position of one element then you'd have to loop through your `List` and update each element that is being shifted. There's no pre-built method which can do your job.

Comment: @Goion LinkedList is not going to be of any help here (it is, virtually always, performance-wise an utter disaster. You can have a long and fruitful java career and never, ever, run into a use-case where LL was the right move).

Comment: @rzwitserloot In array you have to copy all the elements to shift them down. In that case LinkedList has a slight edge. Also, I said OP **might** gain some efficiency. LinkedList will be worse than Array in other situations but we don't really know what operations matters to OP.

Comment: @Goion .insert on a linkedlist is just as slow, as it needs to traverse one-by-one to find the stated index. LinkedList is never, ever, more efficient, unless you are either just adding/removing from start/end (but, use an ArrayDeque instead, much faster), or you're going off of the ListIterator. If you're not using ListIterator, LinkedList sucks. No ifs or caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your objects has a designated position (`setPosition()`). If you want to change the position of one element then you'd have to loop through your List and update each element that is being shifted.

Possible solution written in "pseudocode":

```
public void shiftElement(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
    for (Data data : dataList) {
        if (/* data.getPosition is in range (oldPosition, newPosition] */) {
            // either add or subtract 1 depending on shifting
            data.setPosition(data.getPosition -- / ++) 
        }
    }

    for (Data data : dataList) {
        if (data.getPosition == oldPosition) {
            data.setPosition(newPosition);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```